# When your pandas df has a column of list type removing duplicates from each item

Tags: python, pandas, list

My dataframe has a column of lists and looks like this.

```
     id  source
0    3   [nan,nan,nan]
1    5   [nan,foo,foo,nan,foo]
2    7   [ham,nan,ham,nan]
3    9   [foo,foo]
```

I need to remove duplicates from each list. So I am looking from something like below.

```
     id  source
0    3   [nan]
1    5   [nan,foo]
2    7   [ham,nan]
3    9   [foo]
```

I tried to use the following code which didn't work. What do you recommend?

```
df['source'] = list(set(df['source']))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `.explode` on `source` column, `.drop_duplicates` and `.groupby` back:

```py
df = (
    df.explode("source")
    .drop_duplicates(["id", "source"])
    .groupby("id", as_index=False)
    .agg(list)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id      source
0   3       [nan]
1   5  [nan, foo]
2   7  [ham, nan]
3   9       [foo]
```

---

Or convert the list to `pd.Series`, drop duplicates and convert back to list:

```py
df["source"] = df["source"].apply(lambda x: [*pd.Series(x).drop_duplicates()])
print(df)
```

Comment: I used the `df["source"] = df["source"].apply(lambda x: [*pd.Series(x).drop_duplicates()])` it worked perfectly. Thank you.